# momentjs not working with meteor

Tags: meteor, momentjs, meteorite

I want to use [this package](https://atmospherejs.com/package/bootstrap3-datetimepicker)

I ran `mrt add bootstrap3-datetimepicker` in my Meteor project.
Next I run `mrt install moment` and `mrt update moment` as the instructions tells me.

When I now do `mrt run` I get the following error:

```
=> Errors prevented startup:

While building the application:
error: no such package: 'moment'
```

Why am I getting this?

And if I type `mrt add moment` I get this:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/meteor.js:154
          throw "Error running a command: " + error;
                                            ^
Error running a command: Error: Command failed: => Errors while scanning packages:

While building package `bootstrap3-datetimepicker`:
error: no such package: 'moment'
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the package using 'mrt add moment' rather than 'mrt install moment'?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this issue now, moment.js officially supports Meteor:

```
meteor add momentjs:moment
```

[ref](http://momentjs.com/docs/)